# Pairwise Matrix Operation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want create a pairwise matrix from a list of numbers.
Example: list_num = [2, 4, 9, 1, 7]

As output I'd like to get a list (first row & column should be filled with the items of list_num)
I would also perform an operation (for example, divide each number with each other) and fill the matrix with the results.

What is the easiest way to solve this so that I could use it for other operations?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `np.divide.outer(list_num, list_num)`?

Comment: Thank you, works great for the division! But how could I include a function where I define the operation with the list items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy meshgrid() for custom function pair wise calculations like this:

```
grid = np.meshgrid(list_num,list_num, sparse=True)
>>> grid
[array([[2, 4, 9, 1, 7]]), array([[2],
       [4],
       [9],
       [1],
       [7]])]

>>> def myFunc(x,y):
...   return x+y**x/x+2

>>> z=myFunc(*grid)

>>> z.shape
(5, 5)
>>> z
array([[  6.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+01,   6.78888889e+01,
          5.00000000e+00,   2.72857143e+01],
       [  1.20000000e+01,   7.00000000e+01,   2.91381111e+04,
          7.00000000e+00,   2.34957143e+03],
       [  4.45000000e+01,   1.64625000e+03,   4.30467320e+07,
          1.20000000e+01,   6.83290286e+05],
       [  4.50000000e+00,   6.25000000e+00,   1.11111111e+01,
          4.00000000e+00,   9.14285714e+00],
       [  2.85000000e+01,   6.06250000e+02,   4.48374511e+06,
          1.00000000e+01,   1.17658000e+05]])
```